# How can I ssh over wifi when connected to ethernet too?

Tags: ssh, ethernet, raspberrypi

I have a raspberry pi with a picamera that is connected to a device remotely. I can stream the camera to the local network so that I can record and watch the camera. This works fine, I just have to ssh into the pi and start the stream. However, I also want to connect to another device (that isn't on the wireless network) via ethernet. As soon as I plug the ethernet cable into my laptop, it stops being able to ssh to my raspberry Pi (see screenshot). How can I connect to the raspberry pi via ssh whilst also being connected to another network via ethernet?

I have tried

```
ssh -b [ip address] pi@[pi ip address]
```

with no success

[for the first line, I have ethernet connected. Then I disconnect it and ssh to my pi just fine. I cancel the ssh, connect my ethernet, and try again. It times out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxWu5.png)

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen on the screenshot you provided, when you connect the Ethernet cable, the router on the Ethernet connection (192.168.1.1) becomes your default gateway with metric 100, which is lower than the metric assigned to the router on WiFi connection (10.167.136.1). So all connections to addresses that are not in any of your local networks (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 and 10.167.136.0/255.255.248.0) go via that router.

If 10.167.98.212 is the address of your Pi, it does not belong to any of these networks, so your computer attempts to connect to Pi via the router 192.168.1.1, but it is not reachable over that router. You need to connect to your Pi via the router 10.167.136.1, so you need to add an appropriate route to your routing table. You can for example add a route to 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 via 10.167.136.1. You can add it in the network settings, in the "IPv4" tab, by typing the network address, mask and gateway into the fields below "Routes" header (see screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: If just the screenshot for this answer is in English...

Comment: @wyphan I jut provided a screenshot from my own system :). But regardless of language version, the window **looks** the same, so you can easily match this screenshot to the actual window on your own system...